# unwanted horizontal bar in chrome

Tags: css, windows-7, google-chrome, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

[www.socialgameplex.com](http://www.socialgameplex.com/)

For some reasons I get a long unwanted horizontal scrolling bar that scrolls into blank space on the right side in chrome 9.0.597.98 on windows 7 (and probably in safari as well). The problem was also reported on RockMelt (unkown version)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS: I googled and found some similar problems but I couldnt find a fix for mine.

Comment: I also use Chrome (on Mac) and I see only vertical scroll bar on the right.

Comment: im using windows 7 maybe OS specific bug or something

Comment: Safari shows the bug, but Chrome 10 doesn't, so it's likely a bug in WebKit that has already been fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edit**
after some tests, I find out that the `letter-spacing: -1000em;` of `#title h1 a` create the horizontal scrollbar. If you remove it, the scrollbar is removed also. What is the purpose of this property here? Check if affect something, otherwise remove it.

Comment: awesome it worked, thank you! I used with `overflow-x:hidden`

Comment: @kornesh you did well, much better :)

Comment: but the problem is when I resize the page it doesnt show the scroll page, which will annoy the 800x600 users...any ideas on that?

Comment: @kornesh ok after some tests, I find out that the `letter-spacing: -1000em;` of `#title h1 a` create the horizontal scrollbar. If you remove it, the scrollbar is removed also. What is the purpose of this property here? Check if affect something, otherwise remove it.

Comment: EPIC that works perfectly! thanks alot for your concern and time :)